# How to test a service if it has an injected component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to test a service that manages a component. Inside my slideInComponent, other components will be created dynamically. I want to test call `open(formComponent, param)` in the service, and make sure the formComponent is created inside the slideInComponent host. But slideInComponent is passed to my service like this

```
// service
   setSlideComponent(slideComponent: IxSlideInComponent): void {
     this.slideInComponent = slideComponent;
   }
  open(formComponent, param) {
   this.slideInComponent.openSlideIn(formComponent, params);
  }

//component
   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.slideInService.setSlideComponent(this);
   }

// unit tests
  const createService = createServiceFactory({
    service: IxSlideIn2Service,
    providers: [
      mockProvider(Location),
    ],
    declarations: [
      IxSlideIn2Component,
    ],
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createService();
  });
```

During the execution of the unit tests, the IxSlideIn2Component is not created. And from the service I get the following error
*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'openSlideIn').*
I don't want to mock the IxSlideIn2Component because I want to check that a formComponent appeared in its host.
How can I test my service?